# Where put mcode.sty

Tags: packages

This question has been asked and supposedly answered before, but I can't make sense of the answers so I thought I'd ask my own question and hope for the best.

So, I use mcode.sty a lot and as things are now I have to copy that file into every folder where I have tex files that use mcode. What "central place" can I put it so I don't have to copy it all the time?

What I've tried:

> sudo mkdir /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mcode
>
> sudo cp ~/.../mcode.sty /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mcode

It doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried `mkdir ~/texmf/tex/latex/` and then `mv mcode.sty ~/texmf/tex/latex/`?....

Comment: Still relevant (and/or duplicate): [Where do I place my own `.sty` or `.cls` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764)

Comment: A jungle of answers, none as clear and to-the-point as cmhughes' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
mkdir ~/texmf/tex/latex/
```

and then (assuming you're in the directory that contains `mcode.sty`)

```
mv mcode.sty ~/texmf/tex/latex/
```

See [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te) for further details.